# Books of NT written after the assumption of Mary

Tags: virgin-mary, assumption-of-mary

Assuming for the moment that the Assumption of Mary is a historical event (a statement with which certainly some Christians disagree), which books of the New Testament can be considered as written after the assumption of Mary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them.  Jesus was 33 when he died.  If she were 12 - 20 years old at his birth, then she would have been 45 - 53 years old at his death.  Which is quite old for people at that time.  The earliest known books of the New Testament were [written around 45-55 CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dating_the_Bible#The_New_Testament).  This would have her age between 57 - 75 year old - which would not be consistent with the average age of [humans in the first century](http://www.preventingtruthdecay.org/firstcenturylifespans.shtml).  I am assuming year 0 for Jesus' birth.  However [there are reasons to suspect](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5652/4277) that his birth was as early as 6BC which would make her that much older.

Furthermore, it would have been highly unlikely that at Mary's age and potential fame, would have survived the [First Jewish-Roman War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War). Please consider [reading this article](http://taylormarshall.com/2011/08/in-what-year-was-mary-assumed-into.html) which dates the assumption no later than 70 AD.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dating_the_Bible)

> The first book written was probably 1 Thessalonians, written at around 50 AD. The last book of the canon is the Book of Revelation said to be written by John of Patmos during the reign of Domitian (81-96).

The earliest reference (that I could find) to the Assumption of Mary is found in [Pseudo-Melito](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/mary-full-of-grace) by Saint Epiphanius of Salamis dated at 300 AD

> If therefore it might come to pass by the power of your grace, it has appeared right to us your servants that, as you, having overcome death, do reign in glory, so you should raise up the body of your Mother and take her with you, rejoicing, into heaven. Then said the Savior [Jesus]: ‘Be it done according to your will’(The Passing of the Virgin 16:2–17)

From the [answer given by Affable Geek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/do-people-go-to-heaven-immediately-when-they-die/15404#15404) and from the quoted text it can be derived that Mary was *sleeping* or *dead* until the time of the Assumption; she could have been in this state for many years before the Assumption.

Due to the significance of the event and the timing of the writings of Saint Epiphanius, it should not have happened not too long before the event was written down (lets say 100 years, i.e. 200AD).

Thus from the difference in time it is unlikely that any books of the Bible was written after Mary's Assumption.

---

From the comments with [Matt Gutting](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/12563/matt-gutting)

From [ccel](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf08.vii.xliv.html) it is said that Mary's Assumption happened in the second year ... after Christ had vanquished death.

From [jimmy akin](http://www.ncregister.com/blog/jimmy-akin/when-precisely-did-jesus-die-the-year-month-day-and-hour-revealed)

> There is not enough time between the fifteenth year of Tiberius Caesar--A.D. 29--and the next year's Passover to accomodate a ministry of at least two years. As a result, the traditional date of Jesus' death--Friday, April 3, A.D. 33--must be regarded as the correct one.

Thus Mary's Assumption happened 35 A.D.

All of the New Testament books were written after Mary's Assumption

Comment: My question was "... after assumption of Mary", not "... after the earliest reference to the assumption of Mary".

Comment: I don't see how that answer implies that the assumption of Mary was contemporaneous with the first mention of her assumption. How do you deduce that?

Comment: @MattGutting does it make a bit more sense now? I'll edit again if necessary.

Comment: It makes sense, sort of; but I disagree with your statement "it should not have happened not too long before the event was written down." Especially since Epiphanius [describes the event](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf08.vii.xliv.html) (second paragraph) as happening "in the second year ... after Christ had vanquished death". Of course, you could deny that Epiphanius' description of the timing is correct; but in that case you might just as well deny that his description of the event is historical, too - in which case the question makes no sense in the first place.

Comment: @MattGutting Interesting read, thanks. True, there are a few issues with my answer, for me the main issue being just because the writings Epiphanius were the only to survive until now does not mean that there weren't before him. But just putting it out there, not every christian believes that the Assumption happened, just have a look at this link http://www.christiantruth.com/articles/assumption.html

Comment: Understood; but the question was written with the implicit assumption (no pun intended) that the Assumption is a historical fact. If you're going to assume its historicity, then you ought to assume that there's at least a *prima facie* case for the truth of its earliest description; and thus for the truth of the statement "The Assumption took place about 2 years after the Resurrection." I don't see a *prima facie* case for the truth of your statement about timing, at least if you assume the truth of Epiphanius' story. I'll edit the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @MattGutting I was unaware of this information of the 2 years, and I think it will be wrong for me to answer it in that fashion since it is your answer, and from your reference I will agree. Thus Mary's assumption was A.D. 35; thus the answer is `all of the New Testament books` :D but what bothers me from this is: why wasn't it mentioned anywhere in the Bible? It's not as if it was a small event.

Comment: @MattGutting Made an edit to include our discussion in the answer. Note, I feel that it is your answer, not mine. This was interesting :)

Comment: @Barnstokkr As you know, women in the Bible were not highly regarded - often it's difficult to determine which Mary is being talked about.  I believe a combination of this and the first books being written about the same time is the reason why it is not mentioned in the Bible.  It's not like someone could write a blog post about her assumption real quick or put something on YouTube, the process of writing books was more involved.  Then throw in the whole canonization process...